# boost te memory access failure with visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, c++17, type-erasure

I am looking at using the [`boost te`](https://github.com/boost-ext/te) lib in a project compiled with visual c++  (*MSVC 19.29.30153.0* with c++ standard 20). I take the simpilest example [**erase it**](https://github.com/boost-ext/te?tab=readme-ov-file#erase-it) which is essentially:

```
struct Drawable {
  void draw(std::ostream &out) const {
    te::call([](auto const &self, auto &out) { self.draw(out); }, *this, out);
  }
};

struct Square {
  void draw(std::ostream &out) const { out << "Square"; }
};

int main() {
  te::poly<Drawable> d = Square{};
  d.draw();
}
```

This compiles, but at runtime fails at this point in `te::poly`:

```
  return reinterpret_cast<R (*)(void *, Ts...)>(self.vptr[N - 1])(
      self.ptr(), std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
```

With a read access violation:

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
> self was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

If i add in a line to watch the variable:

```
auto my_pointer = self.ptr();
```

It does indeed fail to call this, and on inspecting the variables:

```
self    {vptr=0x00007ff6698614e2 {check_te_windows.exe! ...
+       __vfptr 0x00000142775a64a0 {0x000000fdfdfdfdcd} void * *
+       vptr    0x00007ff6698614e2
```

The vtable pointer does appear to be broken. This library has worked for me in clang, gcc and intels oneapi compiler. Here is a gcc live example: https://godbolt.org/z/boKaY19oj

Does anyone know what the problem might be on visual c++ compiler?

Answer (score 2):

In the class template `poly` the constructor initializer list **shows** the initializer for `vtable` before `storage`, but `storage` is still initialized first, because of declaration order:

```
  constexpr explicit poly(T &&t, std::index_sequence<Ns...>) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T_,T&&>)
      : detail::poly_base{},
        vtable{std::forward<T>(t), vptr,
               std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ns)>{}},
        storage{std::forward<T>(t)} {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ns) > 0);
    static_assert(std::is_destructible_v<T_>, "type must be desctructible");
    static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<T_> ||
                  std::is_move_constructible_v<T_>,
                  "type must be either copyable or moveable");
    (init<Ns + 1, std::decay_t<T> >(
         decltype(get(detail::mappings<I, Ns + 1>{})){}),
     ...);
  }
```

That's suspect, but what's even more suspect is the double `std::forward` which may invite a double-move from the `t` argument. In your sample, this suspect constructor is indeed invoked with the following template parameters:

```
constexpr boost::ext::te::v1::poly<I, TStorage, TVtable>::poly(T&&, std::index_sequence<Ns ...>);
// with T = Square;
// T_ = Square
// long unsigned int ...Ns = {0}
// I = Drawable
// TStorage = boost::ext::te::v1::dynamic_storage
// TVtable = boost::ext::te::v1::static_vtable
// std::index_sequence<Ns ...> = std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, 0>
```

Instrumenting the Square class to prohibit the move make it not compile: https://godbolt.org/z/v4bjYf18b

### IDEA 1

Based on these observations, you might think to avoid rvalue-arguments (your temporaries): https://godbolt.org/z/cMhd6Pa4h (of course, no problem on GCC, but check on MSVC?)

```
int main() {
    Circle c;
    Square s;
    draw(c); // prints Circle
    draw(s); // prints Square
}
```

### IDEA 2

You might flip the declaration order of the `poly` members from:

```
TStorage storage;
TVtable vtable;
```

to:

```
TVtable vtable;
TStorage storage;
```

Of course, this changes layout and depending on nefarious practices might cause other things to change behaviour.

### Summary, Pointers

Regardless, I'd suggest raising the issue with the TE devs.

Also consider using Boost Type Erasure, which is properly part of Boost: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html

Comment: Nice answer! Do you know what the best part of the boost type erasure lib that would allow me to make a type erased interface like the boost::te lib linked?

Comment: When i look i find that the concepts that the typeerasure lib presents look harder to use in basically every way.

Comment: I never said that `te` isn't easier. I just mentioned Boost because you tagged it with [tag:boost] (also, it is unsettling to me that minimal changes to the first tutorial example make a crash)

Comment: 0 changes to the first tutorial make it crash if you compile with MSVC. I know you said nothing about the difficulty of boost typeerasure, I am just searching for good (or any) tutorial about using it for simple polymorphic interface design.

Comment: I’m sure the documentation tries that, but I don’t have much of a head start, I usually handcode any TE container I need, it just seems like a trivial amount of work and makess me think carefully about my interfaces, which I find therapeutic :)

Comment: Yeah i used to do that as well, but the concept boost::te and like foly::poly use to generate these interfaces super easily makes them a no-brainer swap out for virtual class polymorphism. And the value semantics just work so well. I am sad that all along it was actually doing naughty things.

Comment: I think there’s a lot of merit to it. The implementation seems elegant too. I wonder whether it just suffers from too many features with too little testing? Anyways, I’m glad to have seen it, I might consider a poly implementation that has been well-vetted. I wouldn’t throw the baby with the bathwater, perhaps the issue is really minute, but I’m currently not qualified to diagnose it.

Comment: If you find one, let me know, there are several mentioned on the boost::te page, but they carry a lot more baggage