# Is it legal to `reinterperet_cast` to the child of a non-virtual object?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, undefined-behavior

This is related to the question about type erasure here: [boost te memory access failure with visual c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78037810/boost-te-memory-access-failure-with-visual-c). Feel free to edit the title if you think you can phrase this a better way.

In the type erasure library, a trick is performed which is essentially akin to the following:

```
struct implementer {
  void func(){};
};

struct base {
  virtual void f() const = 0;
};

struct poly : public implementer, public base {
    void f() const {}
};

template <typename T>
void call(const T& v) {
    const auto& b= reinterpret_cast<const base &>(v);
    b.f();
}

int main() {
    poly p;
    implementer &i = p;
    call(i);
}
```

The key here being that because you are passing the implementer to the call function, `reinterperet_cast` must be used to get the poly part out and do the retrieval of the erased function. This compiles and runs (correctly getting the base vtable) in gcc and clang.

https://godbolt.org/z/os9W71av6

It also compiles in MSVC, but when I run it, the `reinterperet_cast` breaks the vtable for the value `b` leading to a read access violation:

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
> b was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

So the question then is **is this type of cast legal in c++, or is it undefined behaviour?**

Comment: This is illegal. `b` references `implementer` storage that does not point to the `vtbl`.

Comment: Hmm. `b` references `poly` storage afaict.

Comment: @Brandon yeah, it should, but whether MSVC has to make this reinterperet cast work properly or not, i am not sure

Comment: @273K `b` is the same as `v` which is a reference (type `implementer`) to `p` which is `poly`. Are you saying that converting this way doesn't have to get the vtable right?

Comment: Even if everything is allowed, you would be calling a pure virtual function.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I would be calling a virtual function on a reference to a base class, which should go to the vptr and resolve the virtual function. The vptr is broken though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why this seems to "work" on GCC/Clang on Linux:

`implementer` is subject to empty base class optimization and is placed in the first zero bytes of `poly`. The next 8 bytes store the vtable pointer and all zero members of `base`.

This means that `p`, `static_cast<implementer&>(p)` (`i`) and  `static_cast<base&>(p)` all have the same address.

You still have UB because the `reinterpret_cast` doesn't point to a `base` object, but that can be fixed by a `std::launder`:

```cpp
const auto& b = *std::launder(&reinterpret_cast<const base &>(v));
b.f();  // No longer UB
```

---

Why this doesn't work on MSVC/Clang with the Microsoft ABI:

Since `poly` isn't standard layout, the members are allowed to be rearranged. Crucially, `implementer` being stored in zero bytes at the beginning is not guaranteed. The Microsoft ABI stores 8 bytes for the vtable pointer / `base` and then zero bytes for `base`.

This means `&i != &p` (it is 8 bytes greater, `&i == reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + sizeof(void*)`).

So that means that your `reinterpret_cast` is at the wrong address. You would have to adjust the pointer again on Windows:

```cpp
const auto& b = *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<const base *>(&v) - 1);
b.f();
```

The amount you need to adjust would obviously be different depending on the exact layout of the class.

---

What you are doing is essentially a sidecast. If you make `implementer` virtual you can do this with a `dynamic_cast`:

```cpp
struct implementer {
    void func() {}
    virtual ~implementer() = default;
};

// ...

template <typename T>
void call(const T& v) {
    const auto& b = dynamic_cast<const base &>(v);
    b.f();
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Making it virtual is not really an option, because this is for understanding the type erasue library linked in the question. But it is clear that the lib is non-conformant, not the compiler